# "assignment discards 'const' qualifier" error on non-const pointer

Tags: c, pointers, constants

In the following function:

```
char *mystrtok(const char *input, const char *delim,char *rest) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; input[i] != *delim && input[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        continue;
    }
    char *result = malloc(sizeof(char) * (i + 2));
    memcpy(result, input, i + 1);
    result[i + 1] = '\0';
    if (input[i + 1] != '\0') 
        rest = input + i + 2;
    else
        rest = NULL;
    return result;
}
```

I am getting `assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type` for the line `rest = input + i + 2`, however, as you can see, rest is not a constant pointer. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: " as you can see, rest is not a constant pointer". You can't assign a const (`input`) to a non-const (`rest`) member.. that's exactly what the error message says. You are trying to wisk it away (`discard`), but you can't do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`input` is a pointer to a constant char, and you're assigning it to a pointer to a **non-constant** char. [This here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/general/article.php/c6967/Constant-Pointers-and-Pointers-to-Constants.htm) might be an interesting reading for you.

Comment: @yasar11732 then you need `char * const`  - the pointer is constant, not what it points to.

Answer (score 3):

you could also cast your 'input' variable with a (char*) type which would resolve the warning.  just be careful using explicit casts like this so as not to modify constants themselves.

```
rest = (char*)input + i + 2;
```

Comment: I tried that and I still get the warning.

Answer (score 0):

change the prototype to

```
char *mystrtok(const char *input, const char *delim, const char *rest);
```