# Discarded 'const' qualifier at assignment

Tags: c, pointers

i have the following code -

```
int acb(const uint16 *MsgPtr) 
{

uint16 *p = (MsgPtr + 1);
printf("%d", *p);

}
```

i get the following warning - discarded 'const' qualifier at assignment for the line above printf. How to resolve?

Comment: Don't use `const` qualifier? If you want to modify an object passed then it makes no sense to use `const` (and ensure the object passed is actually modifiable -- otherwise, undefined behaviour...).

Comment: @BlueMoon Or *use* the `const` qualifier, since the `const` doesn't apply to the object being passed.

Comment: but i am not modifying the msgptr right? then why the error?

Comment: `uint16 *p = (MsgPtr + 1);` should be `const uint16 *p = (MsgPtr + 1);`. You do not modify the values. You should also add a `return 0;` or similar.

Comment: @juanchopanza I didn't know (still don't) whether that's all OP had or actually wanted to modify the object. I'll leave it to you (and others) to see it through its conclusion :)

Comment: possible duplicate of ["assignment discards 'const' qualifier" error on non-const pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113386/assignment-discards-const-qualifier-error-on-non-const-pointer)

Answer (score 6):

The argument to `acb` is a pointer to a constant `uint16`, the pointer you're creating is not pointing to a constant. This discards the `const` qualifier.
Either remove `const` from the argument passed to the function or make `p` point to a `const uint16`.

**Why is this the case?**
You tell the compiler you guarantee you won't change what `MsgPtr` points to, but then create a pointer which can modify what `MsgPtr` points to by `*(p - 1) = ...;`

Comment: thank you for the answer. i have one more question, i also get a misra warning that variable p increases capability. any idea what it is?

Comment: Most likely you removed `const` in the function parameters and added `const` to what `p` points to. Both of the `uint16` should be `const`, or none of them. Also, consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark under the voting buttons if this answer was satisfactory :-)

Answer (score 2):

> How to resolve?

1. Read and understand the error message. In this case, the error message is pointing out a discrepancy between the type of `p` (`int16 *`) and the type of `MsgPtr` (`const int16 *`). If you don't understand the error message, **ask about the error message** rather than asking how to resolve the error message.
2. Since you've read and understood the warning about the missing `const` qualifier, it ought to make sense that you can either add a `const` qualifier to one or remove the `const` qualifier from the other. One of those will generally be the most sensible solution, but they're not the only solutions: You could also explicitly cast the `const` away, or use the `-Wno-discarded-qualifiers` compiler flag to suppress the warning; as the courts have heard a million times, *it's only undefined behaviour if you attempt to modify an object defined as `const`.*

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to assign a `const uint16*` value to a `uint*` pointer . Compiler issues a mere warning in such cases .But you have to gaurantee that you won't try to change what `MsgPtr` has .

Therefore , change type of `p` to `const uint16 *`(With `const` ,compiler help you to keep your promise of not modifiying the `MsgPtr` ) or change type of `MsgPtr` to `uint16 *` in argument.