# Warning: Assigning to 'struct __bnode *' from 'const BinNode *' (aka 'const struct __bnode *') discards qualifiers

Tags: c

I'm studying a binary search tree, and defined a struct like below.

```
typedef struct __bnode
{
    Member data;
    struct __bnode *left;
    struct __bnode *right;
} BinNode;
```

and the function I'm having problem with is

```
static void SetBinNode(BinNode *n, const Member *x, const BinNode *left, const BinNode *right)
{
    n->data = *x;
    n->left = left;
    n->right = right;
}
```

But I met the following warning:

> Assigning to 'struct __bnode *' from 'const BinNode *' (aka 'const
>   struct __bnode *') discards qualifiers

I think this is not dangerous enough to warn, but this is because I'm missing something.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show how you are initializing the argument parameters, and calling the function.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113386/assignment-discards-const-qualifier-error-on-non-const-pointer

Comment: Don't use names starting with `__`. Those are reserved for the implementation. Better: `typedef struct BinNode BinNode; struct BinNode { Member data; BinNode *left, *right; };`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code tries to implicitly convert `const BinNode *` to `BinNode *`, discarding `const`. This is unsafe, so you get a warning.

Here's how this code could bite you:

```
// Let's assume 'typedef int Member;' for simplicity

const BinNode zero = { 0, NULL, NULL };

int main(void) {
    BinNode node;
    SetBinNode(&node, NULL, &zero, NULL);
    node->left->data = 42;
    return 0;
}
```

Here we have a global `zero` variable, which is `const`.

The call `SetBinNode(&node, NULL, &zero, NULL);` is fine; `&zero` has type `const BinNode *`, which is exactly what the function prototype says `SetBinNode` takes.

`node->left->data = 42;` also compiles fine. `node->left` is a `BinNode *`; `node->left->data` is a `Member` (i.e. `int` in our example).

But this assignment will likely crash. `node->left` points to `zero` after the call to `SetBinNode`. Because `zero` is `const`, the compiler will probably put it in read-only memory. Now the assignment to `node->left->data` attempts to modify a `const` variable, triggering a segmentation fault.

All of this happens without a complaint from the compiler ... except for the one line in `SetBinNode`.

The solution is to change the type of `SetBinNode` to

```
static void SetBinNode(BinNode *n, const Member *x, BinNode *left, BinNode *right)
```

i.e. remove the `const`. The `const` on the parameters is making promises it can't keep. Even if the function itself doesn't write through `*left` or `*right`, it still makes the objects available through a non-const access path, which can cause trouble later.